# Retrieve elements of a list when writing a R function

Tags: r, list, function

I am coding a R function, and I would like to retrieve some elements of a list.
This is easy to do outside of a function, but I cannot make it run when creating the function.

Please see below a minimal working example of what I want to achieve.

```
#outside a function - it works
A <- list(42)
B <- list(142)

my_list <- list(a=A,b=B)
test = my_list$a
```

-> test is indeed a list of 1 element: 42.

```
#within a function - it does not work
myfunction = function(obj,whatIwant){
  test = obj$whatIwant
  return(test)
}
test2 = myfunction(my_list,a)
```

-> test2 is NULL (empty). I would have expected a list of 1 element: 42.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should study `help("$")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `obj[[whatIwant]]` to get the object:

```
#outside a function - it works
A <- list(42)
B <- list(142)

my_list <- list(a=A,b=B)
test = my_list$a

#within a function - it does not work
myfunction = function(obj,whatIwant){
  test = obj[[whatIwant]]
  return(test)
}
test2 = myfunction(my_list, "a")
```